# Deleted /usr/bin/dotnet and pacman -S dotnet-sdk will not install it

Tags: .net-core, archlinux

I am trying to write a WEB api in dotnet core on my Manjaro Arch linux distro.
I installed the edge version of dotnet first (^3) since i like the bleeding edge. I had, however on a different computer already made the project using dotnet 2.2. Therefore i install dotnet 2.2 aswell. This did not work, since the version in /usr/bin/ was still 3.0.

I deleted the exec from /usr/bin and now i cant get it back. I have run `pacman -Su` and `pacman -R`, i have tried rebooting aswell.

**OBS:** the first to times i installed them, i did it with `yay -S dotnet-sdk` which allowed me to choose from the different versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force install of packages that is already installed using `--force` in pacman.

So, you should be able to get the binary again by using `sudo pacman -S dotnet-sdk --force`.

You might also attempt to remove dotnet-sdk before you install, you can do that by running `sudo pacman -Rns dotnet-sdk`. (remove package with configurationfiles and dependencies not required by any other package).